# remove a button from admin menu item - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to remove the Google Analytics from menu items for specific admin user.

```
<?php
    add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links');
    function remove_admin_menu_links(){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'email@address.com' == $user->user_email ) {

            remove_menu_page('edit.php'); // Posts
            remove_menu_page('upload.php'); // Media
            remove_menu_page('link-manager.php'); // Links
            remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
            remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page'); // Pages
            remove_menu_page('plugins.php'); // Plugins
            remove_menu_page('themes.php'); // Appearance
            remove_menu_page('users.php'); // Users
            remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
            remove_menu_page('options-general.php'); // Settings
            remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=gadwp_settings' ); // Google Analytics

        }
    }

?>
```

All but the Google Analytics seem to work.

I've tried using google_analytics.php on the off chance it might exists, but resorted to using the button id "page=gadwp_settings" and admin.php.

As the above didnt work, I searched for an alternative option and found;

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );

  function remove_menus() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;

    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r($menu);
    // print_r($submenu);
    // echo '</pre>';

    // If you're not the site creator
    // Hide some menus
    if ( wp_get_current_user()->ID != 3) {
      unset($menu[20]); // Removes 'Pages'.
      unset($menu[25]); // Removes 'Visibilities'.
      unset($menu[26]); // Removes 'Comments'.
      unset($menu[27]); // Removes 'Testimonials'.
      unset($menu[29]); // Removes 'Email Templates'.
      unset($menu[45]); // Removes 'Contact'.
      unset($menu[65]); // Removes 'Plugins'.
      unset($menu[65]); // Removes 'Google Analytics'.

      unset($submenu['index.php'][10]); // Removes 'Updates'.
      unset($submenu['themes.php'][5]); // Removes 'Themes'.
      unset($submenu['themes.php'][6]); // Removes 'Customize'.
      unset($submenu['themes.php'][11]); // Removes 'Editor'.
    }
  }
```

Some of the above seem to work, removing some of the menu items, but then runs into issues and still displays some of the items and some items are removed but arent listed.

Comment: Button 'Menu' items, (top_level) running down the left hand side of the wordpress admin screen - I have a couple of admin users accessing the site and we have far to many pluging menu items viewable. We don't want to use Adminimise nor change the users  Role

Comment: So to update this feed... I've deided to use the first of the removal options and added a few more plugins that have main side, top-level menus which I want to remove, but I've noticed that anything using the href="admin.php" doesn't get removed

Comment: eg. admin.php?page=plugin_addition wont dissapear?